# NuoDB setup on Docker for MacOS. Connection to NuoDB failed. [08S01] Could not connect to any host

Tags: macos, docker, nuodb

I have set up NuoDB locally using docker image.
It works fine and I can access a database console and run queries by accessing `http://localhost:8888/explorer.jsp`.
But when I'm trying to connect to the database using JDBC I got error:

> Connection to NuoDB failed.
>   [08S01] Could not connect to any host [localhost]. Errors are  [java.io.IOException: Operation time out (Connection time out), /172.17.0.3:48006]

As I understand I have successfully connect to NuoDB broker by `localhost:48004`. And After the broker throws me to the database node address `172.17.0.3:48006` where `172.17.0.3` is IP of running docker container that is not accessible from host due to the limitation described at official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers).

**My question is how can I connect to the database? Are there any workarounds?**

Here is my env:
*Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e*.
I run container by command:
`docker run -d --privileged=true -p 48004:48004 -p 48005:48005 -p 48006:48006 -p 9001:9001 -p 8888:8888 nuodb-test`.
Dockerfile and NuoDB setup could be found in my [github repo](https://github.com/bullet-tooth/docker-nuodb).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out this problem.
The solution is next.

1) set up **Docker Toolbox**. It comes with *VirtualBox VM* and you will be able to use VM ip address to connect to DB.

Below described a set of commands to run NuoDB under *Docker Toolbox*.
2) Run `eval $(docker-machine env default)` for switching to Docker Toolbox.
*For switching  back to Docker for MacOS run* `unset ${!DOCKER_*}`.

3) Start container with options `--network=host -e BROKER_ALT_ADDR=$(docker-machine ip)`.
In my case full command is:
`docker run -d --privileged=true --network=host -e BROKER_ALT_ADDR=$(docker-machine ip) -p 48004:48004 -p 48005:48005 -p 48006:48006 -p 9001:9001 -p 8888:8888 nuodb-test`

4) Use `docker-machine ip` command to get your default docker machine IP address. Now you are able to connect by this ip. JDBC connection string example: `jdbc:com.nuodb://192.168.99.100/test` where `192.168.99.100` is docker machine IP address.

As well you are able to connect to database Admin Center by IP `http://192.168.99.100:8888/`.

For more information read [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)